# Global gradle proxy settings?

Tags: java, gradle

Is there any way to simply set up a global, system-wide proxy for gradle?

Yes, I know there is a `systemProp.http.proxyHost`, ...etc settings in the *current* `gradle.properties` file, but it works only in the actual project. But

- I won't set it up in every gradle project
- and I won't change the source code of a project because of my local network configuration.

So, is there any "global gradle.properties" file or so?

Comment: This is my first golden badge for a question visit count. I am so happy! :-)

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Yes it seems possible. See [here](http://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2010/09/gradle-goodness-different-ways-to-set.html), especially:

> We can define a `gradle.properties` file and set the property in this
>   file. We can place the file in our project directory or in the
>   `<USER_HOME>/.gradle` directory. The properties defined in the property
>   file in our home directory take precedence over the properties defined
>   in the file in our project directory. As a bonus we can also define
>   system properties in a gradle.properties file, we only have to prefix
>   the property name with `systemProp`..

The gradle.properties files can be found at the following paths:

```
# windows gradle file
%userprofile%\.gradle\gradle.properties

# linux gradle file
~/.gradle/gradle.properties
```

Comment: On Windows you can find it directly here: %userprofile%\.gradle\gradle.properties
On Linux you'll find it here ~\.gradle\gradle.properties

Comment: @fty4, you can edit my answer to contain the paths from your comment.

Comment: Thumbs up, for accessing user home easily put `%homepath%` in `Run` window.

Answer (score 25):

Copy & paste:

```
systemProp.http.proxyHost=127.0.0.1
systemProp.http.proxyPort=8080
systemProp.https.proxyHost=127.0.0.1
systemProp.https.proxyPort=8080
```

to `gradle global config` = **current user**'s `gradle.properties`

- Linux/Mac/Unices: `$HOME/.gradle/gradle.properties`

  - eg: `/Users/limao/.gradle/gradle.properties`
- Windows: `%userprofile%\.gradle\gradle.properties`

---

More details refer official doc [Accessing the web through a HTTP proxy](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html#sec:accessing_the_web_via_a_proxy)

Thanks to [@Opal's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26524019/1587329), [@fty4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26523804/global-gradle-proxy-settings/47137327#comment97205266_26524019)

Comment: I don't have this file in the .gradle folder!  should I create it manually?

Comment: Yes @OliverD . It does not exist by default

Comment: Can you please check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68919616/android-studio-error-connection-react-native ?

Answer (score 2):

Also do not forget the `no proxy` setting for the exception list, just in case

> systemProp.https.nonProxyHosts=artifactory.yourCompany.com|localhost|*.nonproxyrepos.com