# Error:(23, 17) Failed to resolve: junit:junit:4.12

Tags: java, android, react-native, junit

Why is it that every time I create a new project in Android Studio, it always comes up with:

> Error:(23, 17) Failed to resolve: junit:junit:4.12?

When I remove `testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'` in dependencies it is not a problem anymore.

**build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.okedroid.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
}
```

Comment: Looks like you have the jar not in your repository.

Comment: how to handle it ?I've installed the JDK 7 and also add the path in the environment variables

Comment: Which repository do you use for gradle.

Comment: im using repositories  jcenter in build.gradle(project:MyApplication)

Comment: Looks like the jar's are present http://jcenter.bintray.com/junit/junit/4.12/

Comment: Thanks .. problem resolved I add maven repositories url in build.gradle

Comment: Check my new answer  : http://stackoverflow.com/a/38151747/5733853

Comment: I met the same problem .This problem dispeared after i setup VPN proxy.   I can't access The Google Maven repositories directly for i am in China.

Comment: Don't ask me why but I had got the same error and it was solved changing the JUnit reference from **testcompile** to **compile** as follows: `compile("junit:junit:4.12")`. It is frustrating as I didn't want to include test libraries into the application jar. Btw, I am not developing for Android: `apply plugin: 'application'`

Answer (score 134):

I had the same problem. Solved by adding url for missing repository in the `build.gradle` file:

```
android {
    [...]
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://repo1.maven.org/maven2' }
    }
    [...]
}
```

That's it.

Comment: That definitely solved the issue for me, so atleast i can gradle-sync now

Comment: what was the root cause for this?

Comment: This did solve the problem, but what is that `maven`?

Comment: It should be added above `buildTypes`, otherwise the error [buildTypes cannot be applied to groovy.lang.Closure](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29354337/1179841) will occur.

Comment: What about `jcenter()` ? Is it necessary to eliminate `jcenter()` from repositories?

Comment: where junit.jar is present ,gimme the dir where junit.jar is saved

Comment: change from       testImplementation 'junit:junit:'      to       testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+' –     in build.gradle

Answer (score 34):

Just remove the "testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'" from build.gradle file:

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'//remove this line and sync again... worked for me

androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'}) //if available, also delete these two lines

compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
 }
```

worked for me and I am Happy! :)

*Remember that this is not the actual answer of this question. I mentioned this because it works when you remove above lines.*

Answer (score 26):

Go to File -> Project Structure. Following window will open:

[image]

From there:

1. remove the junit library (select junit and press "-" button below ) and
2. add it again (select "+" button below, select "library dep.", search for "junit", press OK ). Press OK to apply changes. After around 30 seconds your gradle sync should work fine.

Hope it works for you too :D

Comment: I tried this but when I went to add junit back in it wasn't there... wtf

Comment: To manually add junit to the project, open "build.gradle (Module: app)" file from the left side. Add this line: testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12' at the end of the file anywhere in between the dependencies block and finally sync the project by going at TOOLS > ANDROID > SYNC PROJECT WITH GRADLE FILES

Comment: did not work for me. after again adding junit4.12 it gave same error as OP.

Answer (score 15):

add repository in your build.gradle file

```
repositories {
    maven { url 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2' }
}
```

Answer (score 15):

It's not able to get junit library.

```
repositories {
        maven { url 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2' }
    }
```

After adding above line inside android block in build.gradle file, it resolved problem.
This can be because your Android studio doesn't have junit library.

Answer (score 13):

Probably your gradle is incomplete, I recommend you add the following

```
android{
    repositories {
    maven { url 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2' }
}
```

but in some cases won't work , you can completely delete it from you dependencies in your gradle.

**I think it will be OK if you reinstall the android studio with the deleting gradle folder condition which is in user folder `.gradle`**

Answer (score 10):

Here is what I did to solve the same problem. I am behind a firewall, which is same issue as yours I suppose.
So I had tried removing the

```
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12' line
```

but that didnt work for me.
I tried adding below lines of code:

```
repositories {
    maven { url 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2' }
}
```

Even that did not work for me.

I tried removing (-) and readding (+) Junit4.12 from the library dependencies under Module Settings.
Still that did not work for me.

Tried syncing and rebuilding project several times. Still did not work for me.

Finally what I did was to manually download the Junit4.12.jar file from mvnrepository website. I put this jar file in the Androids Workspace under the Project folder inside libs folder.
Then go to Module Settings > Dependencies Tab > (+) > File Dependency >
under Sleect path window, expand the 'libs' folder and you will find the Jar file you copied inside there.
Select the File and click 'OK'
Now remove the previous version of junit4.12 from the list of dependencies.

You should have one entry `"libs\junit-4.12.jar"` in the Dependencies list.
Now click 'OK'.

Now Gradle will rebuild the project and you should be good to go.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I just invalidated cache and restarted the Android Studio.

Answer (score 7):

It happens because HTTPS is blocked by Proxy.
Try to change from default jcenter (which uses HTTPS) into HTTP.

Before

```
repositories {
     jcenter()
}
```

After

```
repositories {
    jcenter {
        //Default one is HTTPS
        url "http://jcenter.bintray.com/"
    }
}
```

Repeat the above step for allprojects.

```
allprojects {
  repositories {
    jcenter {
        url "http://jcenter.bintray.com/"
    }
  }
}
```

Or changing from jcenter to mavenCentral also worked

```
repositories {
   mavenCentral()
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work when proxied, HTTP traffic works, and HTTPS traffic is forbidden.

Comment: Hmm.. This is what I tried to explain in my post. By default it uses HTTPS which is blocked. See Before and After

Answer (score 6):

I'll tryed everithing, but the only thing that helps me resolve the problem was delete the line

```
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
```

from the app gradel.

Answer (score 4):

I received this error after creating a new project. In the build.gradle file, I had this:

```
jcenter()
```

I change it to the following and the error went away:

```
jcenter {
    url "http://jcenter.bintray.com/"
}
```

I think this is because I am behind a firewall and specifying the url like so changes it from https to http

Comment: Thanks a lot . This fix helped me

Answer (score 4):

Probably you are behind proxy. Happened to me, used my mobile tethering (no proxy) rebuild project and error disappeared. Returned to original connection (with proxy) and rebuild with no errors.

Comment: I also needed to specify a proxy for gradle, but I didn't want to add my login details to every project. The answer was to add a gradle.properties to my user directory. More info in this answer - http://stackoverflow.com/a/26524019/542629.

Answer (score 4):

1. Be sure you are not behind a proxy!
2. If you configured your Android Strudio to work with proxy be sure to
   disable that option under the Android Studio preferences
3. Go to gradle.properties under Android view in Android Studio and
   delete all proxy configuration
4. Sync your gradle now
5. Enjoy coding!

Answer (score 4):

**Are you using proxy**? If so, the problem can be in missing network configuration for **https** in your `gradle.properties` file.

AndroidStudio puts automatically your default proxy settings to `gradle.properties` file in your project, but only for http and forgets https.

So basically your `gradle.properties` file needs to contain both http and https config:

```
systemProp.http.proxyPassword=xxx
systemProp.http.proxyHost=xxx
systemProp.http.nonProxyHosts=xxx
systemProp.http.proxyUser=xxx
systemProp.http.proxyPort=xxx

systemProp.https.proxyPassword=xxx
systemProp.https.proxyHost=xxx
systemProp.https.nonProxyHosts=xxx
systemProp.https.proxyUser=xxx
systemProp.https.proxyPort=xxx
```

Answer (score 4):

Mostly this issue will come when ever you update your SDK, at the time of project creation Gradle build fails. If you add the **maven** and **jcenter** repositories to your *build.gradle(Module:app)* your problem will solved.

```
repositories {
    maven { url 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2' }
    jcenter { url "http://jcenter.bintray.com/" }
}
```

These are the two line you have to add after

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
```

***This is how your code look like after adding those two lines***

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

 repositories {
        maven { url 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2' }
        jcenter { url "http://jcenter.bintray.com/" }
    }

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.okedroid.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The error is caused by missing jar files. My simple solution is just by copying all the files that does not resolve to the C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\gradle\m2repository... (your file path may be different). I got around 6 dependencies that cannot be resolved, junit is one of them and the others are com and org and javax. Since I am behind a firewall, even if I added the code for the repository, the Android Studio doesn't seem to access it. I went to the maven repository and downloaded all the files that will not resolve. Problem solved and the Gradle sync without error. But I am a certified newbie with only 1 day experience so I do not not if this is the proper way to do it.

Example error: 
Cannot resolve com:squareup:javawriter:2.1.1

Step 1: I created a path C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\gradle\m2repository\com\squareup\javawriter\2.1.1\

Step 2: I downloaded all the jar files from the maven repository: 
http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/squareup/javawriter/2.1.1/

Step 3: I manually downloaded all the .jar files from this directory

Step 4: I copied them to C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\gradle\m2repository\com\squareup\javawriter\2.1.1\

I repeated this to all the files that did not resolve including the junit.

For junit, here is the directory I created: 
C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\gradle\m2repository\junit\junit\4.12
and then I copied the junit-4.12.jar inside this directory and the junit error disappeared.

Comment: i agree . this was tedious but this only worked for me . i did in windows "cd C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\gradle\m2repository ; mkdir  org\hamcrest\hamcrest-integration\1.3" then copy corresponding jar to folder you created . All jar came from https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/ .

Answer (score 2):

CHANGE your build.gradle like with this, work fine for me:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"
    repositories {
        maven { url 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2' }
    }
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "YOUR PACKAGE NAME"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'
}
```

added

```
    repositories {
        maven { url 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2' }
    }
```

to `android`

Answer (score 2):

Go to File -> Project Structure -> dependency
There you will find ->  junit:unit:4.12

On the right hand side ..select compile from the drop down.
Simple.. its done.

Reference Image: [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5WvS3.png]

Reds'
VV

Answer (score 2):

My installation of Android Studio is completely offline. To resolve these kind of problems I have used the Process Monitor. It showed that a few files are missing within "Android Studio\gradle\m2repository".
I have downloaded all files from

1. http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/junit/junit/4.12/
2. http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/hamcrest/hamcrest-core/
3. repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/hamcrest/hamcrest-parent/1.3/
   (I can only post two links...;-))

and copied these files in "Android Studio\gradle\m2repository". You have to create the structure below "m2repository" as it is below "maven2".
Maybe there are more missing files, but at this time at least Gradle build is finished without errors.

Comment: in all these answers, this was the only one which actually solved my problem (I tested them all !). of course for me it needed more repositories to be added but the solution was the same. the only one which didn't work was "javax.annotation-api/1.2" that after a few tests I had to remove it from dependencies. thanks @Tasko

Answer (score 2):

I was having same problem.

- 1 option: Download junit 4.12.jar and copy it in your lib folder and restart android studio. Benefit u don't have to create any new project
- 2 option: Create a new project having a internet connections and copy all the java and XML code in the newly created project. Benefit this problem will be solved permantly

Answer (score 2):

Look through for many answers but nothing works. Fortunately had found the easy solution. No need to comment junit4.12 or delete it. The problem is here:

```
- androidTestCompile files('libs/junit-4.12.jar')
```

This part shows us the path to look for the file in the library in your's project. No idea why but for some reason by the default it is empty. In my case the path is:

```
C:\Users\arzakhar\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApp\app\libs
```

Sure you can delete this line in code `build.grandle(Module.app)` but you may need it later. Here is the solution:

1 - download junit-4.12.jar or copy it from you Android Studio folder, normally it should be there. In my case, it was here:

```
C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\lib
```

to the directory mentioned above(to your project)

2 - delete & add

[image: here you should re-enter the root to your junit-4.12.jar]

3 - rebuild

4 - work hard

Answer (score 1):

## Remove the line `testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'`

```
dependencies {
  compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
 }
```

After that sync the project again.

Answer (score 1):

Simply try to compile and run you project while having active internet connection.

it worked for me in Android studio 1.5 Ubuntu 15.04

Answer (score 1):

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
       compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
}
```

**Note: Remove testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12' line has been solved my problem.**

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    //testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are behind a proxy. Android Studio will add proxy for http to Gradle, but will not for https.
Add proxy settings for https to gradle.properties

Answer (score 1):

**if you faced this problem you can completely resolve it by changing :**

build.gradle(project: ...)

***replace this***

```
    buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()

    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, but with another problem.

My other problem was that the Gradle build was too slow!

I resolved my problem by doing thisL

If you do like mdew you need to this any time you're creating your project to do this

So if you want to set default option to maven

Do this:

Go to the folder:

```
C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\plugins\android\lib\templates\gradle-projects\NewAndroidProject\root
```

Then open the `build.gradle.ftl` file with notepad++ or notepad
and replace all `jcenter()` with `mavenCentral()`.

EDIT: Why its going down voted? you don't like it?

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't work out why Android Studio was not syncing with gradle. It turned out that it didn't like my VPN, so watch for that!

Answer (score 1):

Go to Go to "File" -> "Project Structure" -> "App"
In the tab "properties". In "Library Repository" [field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xrZM7.png) put 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2' then press Ok.
It was fixed like that for me. Now the project is compiling.

Answer (score 1):

Just connect to Internet and start Android Studio and open your project.
While Gradle Sync it will download the dependencies from Internet(All JAR Files). This solved it for me.
No Editing in Gradle file ,all was done by Android Studio Automatically.
Using Android Studio 2.2 :)

Also don't forget to install Java JDK 1.x(7 or 8 all works fine).

Answer (score 1):

I would love to suggest the solution, which perfects suitable for my situation:

- at first, make sure add

  ```
  repositories {
      maven { url 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2' }
  }
  ```

  to project-level build.gradle file inside the `buildscript {}` block
- then add

  ```
  allprojects {
      repositories {
          maven { url 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2' }
      }
  ```

  to project-level build.gradle file
- the next point is adding

  ```
  repositories {
      jcenter()
      mavenCentral()
  }
  ```

  to module-level build-gradle inside `buildTypes{ }`

Answer (score 1):

In my case, it's just because internet connection. Maybe some proxy or wifi firewall or other things which is probably disturb the connection (Because when I visit the link manually [here](https://akamai.bintray.com/29/2973d150c0dc1fefe998f834810d68f278ea58ec?__gda__=exp=1509281604~hmac=fdd8d8c6176ce2797b554d457c75afbae43dfbaf171191ac991df0ce7676da1e&response-content-disposition=attachment%3Bfilename%3D%22junit-4.12.jar%22&response-content-type=application%2Foctet-stream&requestInfo=U2FsdGVkX195UmEgPMAUggFXseozjVc0D1ockYBTtcZjcgjPBT67shgODeI2rde0edg4p2d4cJ4V92UkqXj4U0POK-i4CIh7Y48uHDqoxxppGcJ_6a1-8Gn3abX19Tlfnullnull) chrome said the file may harm your computer). So I tried using another connection such tethering hotspot from my phone.

Answer (score 0):

It might be it is not able to get it at the specified online location for the jar.check this part of build.gradle (gradle file for project). you might not be having access to the location(firewall or other issues)

```
repositories{
//some location like jcenter() or maven{.some location  }
}
```

Do this:
download the jar 
add this line inside the

```
repositories {
        //previous codes untouched
        flatDir {
            dirs 'location to jar'
        }
}
```

hope that works ;)

Answer (score 0):

When you are not behind a company firewall, using the Android Studio will resolve that issue naturally. But if you are behind a company firewall, this problem will occur. So downloading the files will be a workaround. On your own home network, updating Android Studio will resolve the issue and will ask you to delete those files that you have manually created. Just press OK as it is safe to remove them.

Answer (score 0):

Change repository to `mavenCentral()` except `jcenter()` everything will be Ok

Answer (score 0):

In my case was it was very wired! Besides adding a correct proxy (I'm working within a company), I needed to add the other two libraries in the dependencies:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.0.1'
```

then the error for "junit:junit:4.12" was resolved. 
**Make sure that all of the dependencies in build.gradle match what you import in project structure**

Answer (score 0):

If any one get error "failed-to-resolve-junitjunit4-12" then go to HTTP PRoxy setting check your internet connection. if you are using any proxy server at school / college then set your proxy setting and test connect if it successful then apply setting and run again gradle you will get resolve all error. I try this and i resolve all errors. 
Note : no need to remove Junit....!!
Umair

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem, but when I open my project with an Internet connection on,i got everything cleared when the gradle build a syncing it automatically downloaded the relevant files and the J Unit plugin is required for testing

Answer (score 0):

If none of these answers for you, try clearing the Android Studio cache/restart. That was the only thing that worked for me:

From the file menu option, I selected "invalidate caches/restart".

https://teamtreehouse.com/community/gradle-project-sync-failed-7

Answer (score 0):

You should to address Java to windows.

1. Open this address: 'control panel\system and security\system'
2. From left side choose 'Advanced system settings'
3. In the advanced tab, choose 'Environment Variables'
4. In opened window, below "system variables", choose 'New'.
5. Set variable name to `JAVA_HOME`, and the variable value to the address you installed Java. For example, for me it is `C:\ProgramFiles\Java\jdk1.8.0_66`. After that, click the okay button.
6. Restart Android Studio

Answer (score 0):

In my case the solution was to add

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

to module-level build-gradle inside buildTypes{ }

Suppose that without it AndroidStudio can't download junit from maven.

Answer (score 0):

This answer might be a bit late, but after spending a few hours working through the answers nothing worked for me.
After reading the error log patiently i realized that android studio tried to use a cached version of JUnit with a wrong hash code.
The solution to this was to delete the `C:\Android\caches\modules-2` directory and restart the build.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I believe your given path is different to others since it is C:\Android..., can you tell what is that path actually? for example installation path? SDK path? JDK path? Project path?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I just add:

```
allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Erase all the Junit dependencies and add this on the dependencies.

```
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.3.0'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:rules:1.3.0'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:core:1.3.1-alpha02'
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. It was solved by a simple modification adding "junit:junit:4.+"

```
dependencies {

testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'

}
```

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32180944)

Answer (score -1):

If you're behind a proxy server, just add your proxy settings in **gradle.properties**

```
systemProp.http.proxyHost=x.xx.xx.x

systemProp.http.proxyPort=xxxx

systemProp.https.proxyHost=x.xx.xx.x

systemProp.https.proxyPort=xxxx
```

It worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

Before:

```
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
```

After:

```
testİmplementation 'junit:junit:4.12' 
androidTestİmplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2' 
androidTestİmplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
```

Worked for me.

Comment: The two code blocks are identical.  Please fix this to what you meant it to be.