# Failed to resolve : junit:junit:4.12 in android studio 1.4 on ubuntu

Tags: android, ubuntu, android-studio

When i am creating new project in android studio 1.4 on ubuntu.

I am getting this error when gradle's sync completed on

```
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
```

with message on app/build.gradle

```
Error:(23, 17) Failed to resolve: junit:junit:4.12
Show in File
Show in Project Structure dialog
```

// build gradle (app module)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.abhishek.vearch"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'
}
```

// build gradle (project)

// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

- I have tried [Error:(23, 17) Failed to resolve: junit:junit:4.12](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32519219/error23-17-failed-to-resolve-junitjunit4-12)

Answer (score 6):

Some people have solved by adding below block for missing URL for repository.

```
android {
    .....
    repositories {
        maven { url 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2' }
    }
    .....
}
```

Just to mention : Right click on 'app' folder and goto 'Open Module Settings'. Then move to last tab 'Dependencies' and re-add junit by searching. I tried to add earlier versions but failed to get it working.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I was behind a proxy and the issue has been resolved 
using both

```
jcenter {
    url "http://jcenter.bintray.com/"
}
```

and

```
repositories {
    maven { url 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2' }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if you're using open JDK 8 it could be because of a bug with the cacerts.
Maybe you could try the following to fix the broken cacerts:

```
$ sudo dpkg --purge --force-depends ca-certificates-java
$ sudo apt-get install ca-certificates-java
```

I tried changing my jcenter() to the one with the url as well as trying to change it to maven { url ... } and both didn't work.
This one fixed it for me.

See:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/33440168

Comment: I can verify this fix working under Ubuntu 15.10 with Java 8 (from webupd8team).

Answer (score 0):

If you are facing **issue** with ***junit:junit4.12***. This is the **solution**.

```
repositories {
    maven { url 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2' }
    jcenter { url "http://jcenter.bintray.com/" }
}
```

Add these above two line after

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
```

Answer (score -2):

//remove this line- testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

and sync again... worked for me-

```
dependencies 

{

compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'   //remove this line from here

compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'

}
```

Comment: ya i know that but why would i remove that ? then what if i want to test ?

Comment: I seriously doubt that is a solution.
One guess is that it was using Junit 3 methods, which should be included in android.jar (for example in Api 19), while not needing Junit 4.x.
Or perhaps newer android Apis even have Junit 4.