# android studio gradle error while syncing

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, build.gradle

I just started to learn android studio and created my first project (blank activity) but as you can see in the picture below gradle doesn't sync (after kind of 20-30 minutes loading). I've tried several times and it happens every time. Is there a way to download them separately and sync them in offline mode?

here's my build.gradle:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6uG9J.png)

Comment: are you behind a proxy?

Comment: Could you post your build.gradle (Project: MyApplication) ?

Comment: The error message says **"Failed to resolve: junit:junit:4.12"**. Check whether junit module is available.

Comment: [Refer This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33341121/1611938)

Comment: Im not behind a proxy.