# Failed to resolve: junit:junit:4.12

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, junit4

I just installed Android Studios on my work computer and I created a new blank project. However, I receive the following error.

**Failed to resolve: junit:junit:4.12**

I have attempted numerous solutions from the previous time this question was asked but none of them seem to be working. I tried commenting out the entire line **compile files('libs/junit-4.12.jar')**. I tried copy pasting the jar file from the Android studio lib folder to my project lib folder and adding it as a library. On top of that,the gradle always takes more than 10 minutes to build. So any solution I want to try takes me a while. Please help.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.mabbasi.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso
core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile files('libs/junit-4.12.jar')
}
```

**build.bradle(Project)**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.1'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: please add you global build.gradle file (this is app specific)

Comment: I'm sorry @MatiasElorriaga , I don't fully understand. Can you tell me in more detail please?

Comment: you should have two build.gradle files in your project.. please add the other one (one is already posted :P)

Comment: Done! Check the edit. Sorry about that @MatiasElorriaga

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Failed to resolve : junit:junit:4.12 in android studio 1.4 on ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32969162/failed-to-resolve-junitjunit4-12-in-android-studio-1-4-on-ubuntu)

Answer (score 3):

**[JUnit](http://junit.org/junit4/)** is a unit testing framework for Java programming language.

> JUnit has been important in the development of test-driven
>   development .

At first modify your `build.gradle` from Project Level

```
  // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {

        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.1'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

### Duplicate

At first remove `compile files('libs/junit-4.12.jar')` from `build.gradle` **( Module Level)** section .

Then ***Clean-Rebuild-Gradle-Run*** .

Comment: I received the following error **Could not resolve junit:junit:4.12

Comment: @revipod http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32519219/error23-17-failed-to-resolve-junitjunit4-12

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `mavenCentral()` as a repository, and also remove `compile files('libs/junit-4.12.jar')`

```
buildscript {
    ...
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: I must leave work right now but I will try your solution again tomorrow and let you know!