# Android emulator: UpdateCheck: failed to get a URL: 51 (Error)

Tags: android, android-studio, proxy, android-virtual-device, http-proxy

I am developing with Android Studio 1.5 on an emulated Nexus 5 (API v23) with Ubuntu 15.10 x64. I am behind a proxy (`http_proxy` environment variable is set).

Creating a new project, and I get an error straight off the bat. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32566057) fixes it. Next I try to build it, the emulated phone frame loads, but is black (no content shown). The console says this:

```
Android/Sdk/tools/emulator -netdelay none -netspeed full -avd Nexus_5_API_23_x86
emulator: WARNING: UpdateCheck: failed to get a URL: 51 (Error)
emulator: WARNING: UpdateCheck: failed to get the latest version, skipping check (current version '24.4.1'
```

So maybe it's a proxy issue? - BTW: my "gradle.properties" automatically populated: `systemProp.http.proxyHost`, `systemProp.http.proxyUser`, `systemProp.http.proxyPort`.

EDIT: Same error with `Android/Sdk/tools$ ./emulator @Nexus_5_API_23_x86 -http-proxy $HTTP_PROXY`

Answer (score 1):

When used your [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32566057) i got the error in command line as

```
FATAL:.//android/base/sockets/SocketWaiter.cpp:88:Check failed: isValidFd(fd). fd 1064 max1024
```

So this error can be resolved by starting emulator from the command line using this command

```
emulator.exe -avd <avd_name> -no-audio -http-proxy <proxy_name>:<proxy_port>
```