# Error:(26, 17) Failed to resolve: junit:junit:4.12 android studio 1.5

Tags: java, android, gradle, junit, build.gradle

well i can't figure it out i have tried every possible solution i found but nothing worked like this one

[Error:(23, 17) Failed to resolve: junit:junit:4.12](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32519219/error23-17-failed-to-resolve-junitjunit4-12)

the main difference between those two questions is my error is (26,17) and his is (23,17)
here is my build.glade code

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

repositories {
maven { url 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2' }
jcenter { url "http://jcenter.bintray.com/" }
}

android {
 compileSdkVersion 23
 buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"
 defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.vaio.myapplication2"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
   }
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
}
```

Comment: Have you tested other prokects from the maven repository? Is your internet connection working properly? Work offline unchecked in Android Studio? Just out of interest: Why do you assign the repositories in the apps gradle file. By default the are in the project gradle in `buildscript {
    repositories { ...` are you sure it works this way?

Comment: no how i test other pockets i'm a noob here. yes my internet connection is working .work offline is also unchecked .i tried to assign repositories in project glade file and i didn't work