# junit error when creating a new project in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

when i create new project on android studio i receive error :

[image]

and this is the code when i click on show in project :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "org.ashiyane.sepehr"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.3.0'
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error:(23, 17) Failed to resolve: junit:junit:4.12](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32519219/error23-17-failed-to-resolve-junitjunit4-12)

Comment: Please, read [this (how to ask)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and
[this (mcve)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) before asking,
as those will help you get more and better answers from the community. Never add code in images, or links in images... most people wont even check it, to see it they can aid in resolving the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Just comment that line in build.gradle file..

```
//testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your module Dependencies  :
Android Studio > File > Project Structure > Select your Module >Dependencies > + > Library Dependency > check it available or not otherwise update your repository in SDK