# Error in opening new android project

Tags: android, android-studio, build.gradle

I am trying to open new android project, then i will get an error the error is,
Failed to resolve:junit:junit:4.12
Error(23,13)
please help me to fix it.

**build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.akhil.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 22
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
}
```

Comment: post your `build.gradle` file here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error:(23, 17) Failed to resolve: junit:junit:4.12](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32519219/error23-17-failed-to-resolve-junitjunit4-12)

Comment: @Akhil see my answer below.

Comment: What repositories do you have in your root build.gradle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `compile 'junit:junit:4.12'` from the `build.gradle` file.

so the finally code look like this

**Code :**

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
}
```

Comment: @Akhil glad to help you.

Answer (score 0):

comment out junit dependency and then rebbuild the project.