# Fixing A Run Time Error for An Android Program

Tags: android

when I was trying to run a simple program  , I got an error related to Gradle :

```
Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration':app:_debugUnitTestCompile'.
> Could not resolve junit:junit:4.12.
 Required by:
     MyApplication:app:unspecified
  > Could not resolve junit:junit:4.12.
     > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/junit/junit/4.12/junit-4.12.pom'.
        > Could not GET 'htps://jcenter.bintray.com/junit/junit/4.12/junit-4.12.pom'.
           > Connection to htps://jcenter.bintray.com refused .
```

I don't know how can I fix it , please help .( I am currently using the android studio version 2.1.2 )
my module build-gradle includes these codes:

```
 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

 android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.n5110.myapplication"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
     }
   }
 }

   dependencies {
       compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
       testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
       compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
       compile 'com.android.support:design:23.3.0'
   }
```

Comment: Share your module gradle file.

Comment: @Shaishav , Sry I've just started  learning Android and I'm beginner , how can I share the module gradle file ? ( where is it exactly ? )

Comment: If your are on Android Studio then, there should be a file named `build.gradle` in the `app` folder of your project

Comment: @Shaishav, thanks . I found these codes there :

Comment: @Shaishav that's too long , I'll add them at the end of my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problematic part with your `gralde.build` is this line:

```
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
```

This is a unit testing library. If you are just starting and are probably not gonna write testcases for your project then, you can resolve the issue by simply deleting the line. If however you essentially need that library then refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32519219/error23-17-failed-to-resolve-junitjunit4-12).