# Custom classpath for Gradle for Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, junit, android-gradle-plugin

My company admin helped me to install the `Android Studio`, but when I try to create a project, it come with error

> Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
>   > Could not download junit.jar (junit:junit:4.12)
>   > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/junit/junit/4.12/junit-4.12.jar'.
>   > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/junit/junit/4.12/junit-4.12.jar'.
>   > sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

After investigate the log file, I found that `Gradle` cannot download the `JUnit` library, which possibly caused by firewall.

> org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpRequestException: Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/junit/junit/4.12/junit-4.12.jar'

However, if I use browser go to this URL, I'm able to grab this jar (with warning, but can bypass it).

So my question is, ***can I pass this jar to `Gradle` or append to classpath for `Gradle`?***
And one more thing, I don't have admin right and can't modify the `Program Files`

Thanks in advance!

***UPDATE***
At the end, I have solved this problem by following steps:

1. Fix the SSL problem, as my company's firewall will alter the certificate, I need to add that into java keystore ([Details in Here](http://nodsw.com/blog/leeland/2006/12/06-no-more-unable-find-valid-certification-path-requested-target))
2. After fixed the SSL problem, it throw another exception `Failed to resolve: junit:junit:4.12` and more other library, I follow another post "[Error:(23, 17) Failed to resolve: junit:junit:4.12](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32519219/error23-17-failed-to-resolve-junitjunit4-12)" to solve this.

Hope this can help if anyone have the same problem.

Happy coding~~~

Answer (score 0):

A very simple way is you can put the junit jar file in the android project "libs" folder

Gradle will add this to the classpath, if you open the `build.gradle` file, you will get something like

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    ......
}
```

Comment: Thank, but still have the same issue

Comment: After put the jar to this folder, did you refersh the gradle project?

Comment: I have tried `Sync Project with Gradle Files`, Close Project and open it again.  Is it same as refresh the gradle?

Comment: Should the same, can you find the junit jar in the "External Libraies" in the project view?

Comment: I can't, maybe I misunderstood your `libs` folder? Is it the `libs` in my project or it have a folder named `android project`? Thanks

Comment: It's in your project root folder.