# stuck on androiddebugCompileTest and shows error on gradle building

Tags: android, build.gradle

## this is my build.gradle app module##

```
 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 23
        buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"
        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.mytech.wv"
            minSdkVersion 19
            targetSdkVersion 23
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
            testInstrumentationRunner 


        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
        androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
            exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
        })
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
        compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
    }
```

**----------
** this is the error i m getting  after 10-20 min of  gradle building   (androiddebugCompileTest) ****

```
 Error:Error:Failed to resolve: junit:junit:4.12
   Error:Error:Failed to resolve: javax.inject:javax.inject:1
   Error:Error:Failed to resolve: javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:1.2
   Error:Error:Failed to resolve: com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:2.0.1
   Error:Error:Failed to resolve: org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:1.3
   Error:Error:Failed to resolve: org.hamcrest:hamcrest-integration:1.3
   Error:Error:Failed to resolve: com.squareup:javawriter:2.1.1
```

Comment: see this link same as your question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32519219/error23-17-failed-to-resolve-junitjunit4-12

Answer (score 0):

```
 Error:Error:Failed to resolve: junit:junit:4.12
```

comment this and rebuild. It is not that much necessary. Did you build online ?