# Android Studio error connection - react native?

Tags: java, android, react-native, gradle, apple-m1

I have app and want to build in the M1 (maybe there's issue with them)
so after run
npx react-native run-android

I got this error

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'orderApp'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.2.
     Required by:
         project :
      > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.2.
         > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/4.1.2/gradle-4.1.2.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/4.1.2/gradle-4.1.2.pom'.
               > PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
      > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.2.
         > Could not get resource 'https://maven.google.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/4.1.2/gradle-4.1.2.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://maven.google.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/4.1.2/gradle-4.1.2.pom'.
               > PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
   > Could not resolve com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.0.
     Required by:
         project :
      > Could not resolve com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.0.
         > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/gms/google-services/4.3.0/google-services-4.3.0.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/gms/google-services/4.3.0/google-services-4.3.0.pom'.
               > PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
      > Could not resolve com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.0.
         > Could not get resource 'https://maven.google.com/com/google/gms/google-services/4.3.0/google-services-4.3.0.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://maven.google.com/com/google/gms/google-services/4.3.0/google-services-4.3.0.pom'.
               > PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

My Internet connection is well!

Build.gradle file 'root file'

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "30.0.0"
        minSdkVersion = 21
        compileSdkVersion = 30
        targetSdkVersion = 30
        supportLibVersion   = "28.0.0"
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath('com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.2')
        classpath('com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.0')
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android")
        }
        maven {
            // Android JSC is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/jsc-android/dist")
        }

        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://www.jitpack.io' }
        maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }

    }
    
}
```

gradle-wrapper.properties

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.9-all.zip
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
```

app/build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'gradle.plugin.com.onesignal:onesignal-gradle-plugin:[0.12.10, 0.99.99]'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.onesignal.androidsdk.onesignal-gradle-plugin'
apply plugin: "com.android.application"
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

import com.android.build.OutputFile


project.ext.react = [
    enableHermes: true,  // clean and rebuild if changing
]

apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"
apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native-code-push/android/codepush.gradle"


def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = false
def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false
def jscFlavor = 'org.webkit:android-jsc:+'


def enableHermes = project.ext.react.get("enableHermes", false);


android {
    // ndkVersion rootProject.ext.ndkVersion

    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.toot.pos"
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode 2
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    splits {
        abi {
            reset()
            enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
            universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
            include "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "arm64-v8a", "x86_64"
        }
    }
    signingConfigs {
        debug {
            storeFile file('debug.keystore')
            storePassword 'android'
            keyAlias 'androiddebugkey'
            keyPassword 'android'
        }
        release {
            if (project.hasProperty('MYAPP_UPLOAD_STORE_FILE')) {
                storeFile file(MYAPP_UPLOAD_STORE_FILE)
                storePassword MYAPP_UPLOAD_STORE_PASSWORD
                keyAlias MYAPP_UPLOAD_KEY_ALIAS
                keyPassword MYAPP_UPLOAD_KEY_PASSWORD
            }
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
        release {
            // Caution! In production, you need to generate your own keystore file.
            // see https://reactnative.dev/docs/signed-apk-android.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
        }
    }

    // applicationVariants are e.g. debug, release
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here:
            // https://developer.android.com/studio/build/configure-apk-splits.html
            // Example: versionCode 1 will generate 1001 for armeabi-v7a, 1002 for x86, etc.
            def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a": 1, "x86": 2, "arm64-v8a": 3, "x86_64": 4]
            def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
            if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
                output.versionCodeOverride =
                        defaultConfig.versionCode * 1000 + versionCodes.get(abi)
            }

        }
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.0.0'
    implementation project(':react-native-pusher-push-notifications')
    implementation 'com.pusher:push-notifications-android:1.4.4'

    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    //noinspection GradleDynamicVersion
    implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules

    implementation "androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.0.0"

    implementation(project(':react-native-maps')){
       exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-base'
       exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-maps'
    }
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:17.2.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.0'

    debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper:${FLIPPER_VERSION}") {
      exclude group:'com.facebook.fbjni'
    }

    debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper-network-plugin:${FLIPPER_VERSION}") {
        exclude group:'com.facebook.flipper'
        exclude group:'com.squareup.okhttp3', module:'okhttp'
    }

    debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper-fresco-plugin:${FLIPPER_VERSION}") {
        exclude group:'com.facebook.flipper'
    }

    if (enableHermes) {
        def hermesPath = "../../node_modules/hermes-engine/android/";
        debugImplementation files(hermesPath + "hermes-debug.aar")
        releaseImplementation files(hermesPath + "hermes-release.aar")
    } else {
        implementation jscFlavor
    }
}


task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.compile
    into 'libs'
}

apply from: file("../../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle"); applyNativeModulesAppBuildGradle(project)
```

Android studio Network settings
[image: android]

Comment: can you `curl https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/4.1.2/gradle-4.1.2.pom` in the Terminal.app ?

Comment: I got some xml code i guess as result @serv-inc

Comment: Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60720241/gradle-build-fails-due-to-sun-security-validator-validatorexception-despite-inst helps ?

Comment: Sadly no :( @serv-inc

Comment: 1. have you tried updating gradle

Comment: 2. does it work on the command line ?

Comment: 3. does the following work: `openssl s_client -connect repo1.maven.org:443`

Comment: 4. how about the gradle wrapper ?

Comment: 1=> I have last v `6.9` 
2 => which one? 
3 => after run it i got the `Server certificate`  the command works, 4=> i put it in Q @serv-inc

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236404/discussion-between-oliver-d-and-serv-inc).

Answer (score 1):

Picking out your first error

> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
> Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.2.

and you can download

https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/4.1.2/gradle-4.1.2.pom

means there is probably a problem with proxies.

Btw, you can delete `maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }` you already use `google()`

##### 1. Home directory

Please check `~/.gradle/gradle.properties` from home directory

###### 2. Project directory

`gradle.properties` from project directory